# ln[*] in Jupyter notebooks when using the %%bash magic

Tags: bash, jupyter-notebook

I'm working in Jupyter notebooks, when I use the %%bash magic I get the ln[*] (which means the kernel is busy) instead of the ln[number]. The kernel seems to stay busy until I restart it, and it always does this when using %%bash.

It was working fine until last week, when we were moved to Windows 10 pro with a new AVG antivirus - could this be it?

Any help would be great!

Comment: Note - I have tried temporarily disabling AVG but the problem persists

Answer (score 0):

A possible cause is you use the %%bash magic command and not quit with "quit" command,for example the execution result will ask you to keyboard a "ipdb" message when you use "%debug" command ,if you skip this step and execute other cells ,you will get the "[*]" signal and  it means those cells will not execute unless you restart the kernel,hope helpful.